# get json list item with bootstrap table & flat json failed

Tags: json, bootstrap-table

i use bootstrap-table plugin `flatjson` to pasre my json file, my json file as below, but i can't get ActiveConds item.

```
[
    {
                "ActiveConds": [
                    {
                        "ExtraParam1": "",
                        "ExtraParam2": "",
                        "ID": 1,
                        "Params": [
                            240,
                            0,
                            0
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "ExtraParam1": "",
                        "ExtraParam2": "",
                        "ID": 0,
                        "Params": [
                            0,
                            0,
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "EndTime": "2015-8-15 23:59:59",
                "ExtraParam": 0,
                "ID": 1001,
                "Icon": 2,
                "IsBackFlow": 0
        }
]
```

how can i use bootstrap-table plugin "flatjson" to get the value of ActiveConds.ID? `data-field` should be `ActiveCons[0].ID`?  in general, how to get value of list in json file by using flatjson?

Comment: Solved . Use ActiveCons.0.ID

Answer (score 0):

Solved . Use ActiveCons.0.ID, done close it